# ansible empty dictionary conditional

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I had an error when I run this code:

```
- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ my_var|default({}) | combine( {item.key: item.value} ) | default({}) }}"
    with_dict: "{{ my_dict }}"
    when: my_id in authorised[item.key]
```

FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The conditional check 'my_id in authorises[item.key]' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (my_id in authorised[item.key]): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if my_id in authorised[item.key] %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).\nMake sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable\n\nThe error appears to have been in '': but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:...

my_id is a global variable and authorised is an empty dictionary (authorised: {} )

is there a way to add a conditional to skip the tasks when authorised is an empty dictionary. I have just tried

```
when: authorised is defined
when: authorised
```

but it doesn't work. any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19494177/20267 - `authorised|length >0` maybe?

Answer (score 3):

I'm hoping you figured this out on your own, but the issue is that the `with` and `when` clauses are improperly indented. As written, they are attributes of the module not a loop and a conditional on the task.

Corrected:

```
- set_fact:
    my_var: "{{ my_var|default({}) | combine( {item.key: item.value} ) | default({}) }}"
  with_dict: "{{ my_dict }}"
  when: my_id in authorised[item.key]
```